# Multiple recipients using SMS URL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, sms

Is there a way to use the SMS URL to open the SMS app with multiple recipients? I've tried similar approaches to the `mailto:` protocol but it's not playing nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with iOS 4.x you can include multiple recipients as shown below:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1-222-333-4444", @"1-222-333-5555", nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

As you probably noticed, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html) does not mention any support for multiple recipients, so I think the answer is currently "No".

You could file an enhancement request [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).